# Is there any way to get JMX stats whithing my APP programatically

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, jmx, reactor-kafka

I was reading about how to get some stats in java using JMX and I can see that mostly of the solutions that are proposed on the internet uses a client to get them remotelly.

I would like to know if it would be posible to get them programatically inside my code without open a conection (not even to localhost).

I am interested in reading the current the lag for a kafka group, that uses reactor kafka to create the consumers.

thx

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to the MBeanServer then you can run a query with the ObjectName.

Comment: Thank you Gary one question, I have seen implementations to get the MBeanServer that use findMBeanServer and then if the return valus is empty fallback to getPlatformMBeanServer. Why no use getPlatformMBeanServer directly?
In here you can see what I mean: [KafkaMetrics.java](https://github.com/luiztoscano/spring-boot-kmetrics/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure-kmetrics/src/main/java/org/kmetrics/KafkaMetrics.java)